# Non- seperable Hilbert Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I know that an example of non-separable Hilbert space is the space of  almost periodic functions as stated in the book of Israel Gohberg Basic operator theory in p.37, but I need a rigor proof for this, Can anyone help me?
[Definition of almost periodic functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqmDB.png) 
[The rest of the details that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V57dO.png)

thanks.

Comment: Could you give us the definition of almost periodic function you're using?  There are apparently several inequivalent definitions.

Comment: I have added the definition in an image at the beginning of my post .

Comment: I do not know why I am voted down on this question can any one explain to me please?

Comment: The image shows how to prove there is an uncountable orthonormal set.  I assume the reference to the appendix is a proof that this implies the space is not separable.  Which part are you unsure of?  Basically, the image you showed is a rigorous (but not completely detailed) proof.

Comment: No, the reference to the appendix is not a proof. I mean I want a completely detailed proof.

Comment: So do you follow everything up until uncountable orthonormal set => not separable?

Comment: @mathematician ..... No, Frankly speaking the general idea is not clear for me, Could u please explain it for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the image: A function $f\in C(\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{C})$ is **almost periodic** if it is the uniform limit of functions of the form $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k e^{i\lambda_k x}$ (trigonometric polynomials).  Let's call the space of almost periodic functions $E$.

We want to prove that $E$ is a non-separable Hilbert space.

The steps are

1. $E$ is a vector space.
2. $E$ is a Hilbert space: There exists an inner product on $E$ that makes it complete.
3. There is an uncountable orthonormal set using this norm.

The last step proves that $E$ is non-separable using:

**Theorem:** A Hilbert space is separable iff its dimension is finite or countable.

Proof: [Separable Hilbert space have a countable orthonormal basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324538/separable-hilbert-space-have-a-countable-orthonormal-basis)

Now back to the 3 steps.  Step 1:  Suppose $f,g\in E$.  We want to show $\alpha f+g\in E$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$.  We know there exist sequences of trigonometric polynomials $f_n, g_n$ such that $f_n\rightarrow f$ and $g_n\rightarrow g$ uniformly.  Then $f_n+\alpha g_n \rightarrow f+\alpha g$ uniformly (by the properties of limits), where $f_n+\alpha g_n$ are trigonometric polynomials (check this).

Step 2:  We are told to use $\langle f, g\rangle=\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(x)\bar{g}(x)\,dx$.  Check that this is well-defined (the limit converges for any $f,g\in E$) and is a positive definite sesquilinear form.  Is $E$ complete under the norm $\sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle}$? (I feel like there's a clever way to show completeness, but am out of energy at this point.  You can try the straightforward way by constructing a limit from a Cauchy sequence.)

Step 3: $\{e^{i\lambda x}:\lambda\in \mathbb{R} \}$ is an orthonormal set:  First of all, it is clear that these functions are in $E$. It is easy to check that $\langle e^{i\lambda x}, e^{i\lambda x}\rangle =1$ for any $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$.  For $\lambda\neq\mu$, $\langle e^{i\lambda x},e^{i\mu x}\rangle=$ $\lim_{T\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T e^{i(\lambda-\mu)x}dx$.  That this limit equals zero can be checked with basic calculus.