# An orthogonal basis of a Hilbert space is Schauder?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, schauder-basis, hamel-basis

I read that an orthogonal (Hamel) basis $(e_i)$ of a Hilbert space is always a Schauder basis. I can see why; if $\sum \alpha_i e_i=0$ then taking the inner product with each $e_i$ gives $\alpha_i =0$.

I am confused about the following: take a Hilbert space and an orthogonal Schauder basis $(e_i)$ that is not a basis, e.g. the standard Schauder basis of $\ell^2$. Then $(e_i)$ is in particular linearly independent and thus strictly contained in an orthogonal Hamel basis $(f_i)$, which is a Schauder basis.

But a Schauder basis cannot be strictly contained in a Schauder basis!? - it would contradict the strong linear independence ('strong' meaning we allow countable sums): if $f$ is a member of the larger basis, we can write it as a series in the $e_i$ and this gives a nontrivial series in the $f_i$ that sums to zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Except in the finite-dimensional case there's no such thing as an orthogonal  Hamel basis. Your statement ($*$) "and thus strictly contained in an orthogonal Hamel basis" is simply not so.

Indeed, say $H$ is an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and $B$ is a Hamel basis. Suppose $B$ is orthonormal. Say $e_1,e_2,\dots\in B$. Then the series $x=\sum e_n/n$ converges in $H$. Since $B$ is a Hamel basis, $x$ is also a *finite* linear combination of elements of $B$, and as you note considering $<x,e_n>$ this shows that there exists $n$ such that $1/n=0$.

Comment: Thanks! I misunderstood the statement in [Separable Hilbert space have a countable orthonormal basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324538) - which shows that an orthogonal set is contained in an orthogonal _Schauder_ (not Hamel) basis (in the topologically separable case)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot extend $\{e_i\}$ to a bigger orthogonal basis; it is already a maximal orthonormal set.I don't understand what you mean by 'orthogonal Hamel basis'.

Comment: Ah right, so when one says "orthogonal basis of H" it does not mean a Hamel basis of which every two are  orthogonal, but a maximal (pairwise) orthogonal set? -- I must have misunderstood the statement in [Separable Hilbert space have a countable orthonormal basis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324538)