# How does having Fourier Expansion apply in the proof of separability of a Hilbert space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

A Hilbert space is separable if *and only if* it has a *countable* orthonormal basis.

**Proof.** Assume that $\{ e_j\}$ is an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space $H$. By Theorem (i), it is easy to show that the countable subset of elements $x$ with $\langle x,e_j \rangle$ in the set of rationals for all $j$ is dense. Thus, $H$ is separable.

**Theorem (i).** Every element $x$ of a Hilbert space $H$ with an orthonormal basis $\{ e_j\}$ can be expressed in terms of the Fourier expansion

$$x=\sum\limits_{j=1}^\infty  \langle x,e_j \rangle e_j.$$

**Question**: I don't understand the sentence "By Theorem (i), it is easy to show that the countable subset of elements $x$ with $\langle x,e_j \rangle$ in the set of rationals for all $j$ is dense."

Comment: Presumably you mean a *countable* orthonormal basis? Every Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis.

Comment: This proof seems like it glossed over too many details. Instead, begin by showing that, if $\{e_j\}$ is an orthonormal basis, then finite linear combinations of them (i.e., the span) are dense in $H$. Then show that you can approximate any finite linear combination of $\{e_j\}$ by a finite linear combination with rational coefficients. The latter collection is then countable if $\{e_j\}$ is, showing separability of $H$, as desired.

Comment: (This answer)[https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1939088/442938] explains this proof as @DavidGao has mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the countable subset of elements $x$ with $ \langle x,e_j \rangle$ in the set of rationals for all $j$, i.e.
$$A= \{  x \in H : \langle x , e_j \rangle \in \mathbb{Q} \quad \forall j \in \mathbb{N}  \}$$
Let $y \in H$ and let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Then by Theorem (i), $y$ can be written as $y = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \langle y , e_j \rangle$. Now for each $j \in \mathbb{N}$ choose a rational number $q_j \in \mathbb{Q}$ s.t. $| \langle y , e_j \rangle - q_j | < \frac{\epsilon}{2^{j}}$ which is guaranteed by the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Define $x \in A$ as
$$x : = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} q_j e_j$$
Now observe that
$$\| y-x \| = \| \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (\langle y , e_j \rangle -  \langle x , e_j \rangle ) e_j \| \leq 
 \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} |\langle y , e_j \rangle -  q_j | \| e_j \| \leq  \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac{\epsilon}{2^j} = \epsilon$$ Thus $A$ is dense in $H$.

Comment: Thus defined, $A$ is *not* countable, since it consists of sequences with values in a countably infinite set, namely $\mathbb{Q}$. So the cardinality of $A$, defined here, would be continuum. The correct way to do this should only allow finite linear combinations to be in $A$, instead of allowing infinite linear combinations.

Comment: You're right and thank you for pointing it out.