# Hilbert space has always an orthonormal Schauder basis + what is meant by the dimension of a Hilbert space?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I realized that I have become a bit rusty when it comes to the definition of a basis and have the following question:

Usually, a basis in a Hilbert space, denoted as $H$, is defined as an orthonormal set that is also a Schauder basis. In other words, it's a set $B := (e_i | i \in I) \subset H$, where $I$ may have any cardinality, and $\langle e_i, e_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$ for all $i$ and $j$, such that $\mathrm{span} (B) := \left(\sum_{j \in J} c_j e_j \bigg| J \subset I, |J| < \infty, \text{ and } c_j \in \mathbb{F} \text{ for all } j \in J \right)$ is dense in $H$.

Now, my question would be: Is the dimension of a Hilbert space the number of elements in $B$? (Is this then well-defined because if there is another such basis, is the number then automatically the same etc.)

And does such a basis always exist for a Hilbert space? (Maybe this can be done with Zorn's Lemma?)

Perhaps some seasoned mathematicians can provide me with a quick answer to these questions to help me gain more clarity.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/218092/256128) for a proof of existence of orthonormal bases via Zorn's lemma

Comment: BTW, you should call this the orthogonal dimension. There are different notions of dimension.

Comment: All total orthonormal sets in a Hilbert space have the same **cardinality**. It is called the Hilbert dimension or orthogonal dimension. And two Hilbert spaces over the same field are isomorphic if and only if they have the same Hilbert dimension.

Comment: @Ricky Thank you very much.  Do you know a reference where I can read about "Hilbert dimensions" or "orthogonal dimensions"?

Comment: The [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Hilbert_dimension) has all the facts listed. For proof just consult any functional analysis book, I first learned about them in Kreyszig's Introductory Functional Analysis.

Comment: @Ricky Thanks a lot

Comment: @Ricky, would you consider writing your comments into an answer to help remove this from the Unanswered queue? It appears that you have satisfied the OP's request to their satisfaction.

Comment: Sure. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the *dimension* of a Hilbert space can mean Hamel dimension or Hilbert dimension, which are in general different (Hilbert dimension is no greater than Hamel dimension).

The **Hilbert dimension** (or **orthogonal dimension**) of a Hilbert space is defined as the **cardinality** of a total orthonormal set (orthonormal basis) in that space. It is well-defined because **all** total orthonormal sets in a Hilbert space have the same cardinality. And two Hilbert spaces over the same field are isomorphic if and only if they have the same Hilbert dimension.

The **Hamel dimension** of any vector space is the cardinality of a basis of the space over its base field. It is also well-defined because all Hamel bases of a vector space have the same cardinality.

As a result of Zorn's Lemma, **every** nontrivial vector space has a Hamel basis, and **every** nontrivial Hilbert space has an orthonormal basis. These two bases coincide if and only if the space is finite dimensional. (I learned about these in Kreysig's Introductory Functional Analysis p212)